# Accept Windows Security Alert with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, alert

Environment: 
I have to test a web-application with Selenium. Before accessing the startpage, a windows security alert is thrown. Cause the alert/verification-popup is on os level, it can't be handled by the selenium alert-api.

Workaround: 
To access the page, I wrote a script, which fills username and password and afterward clicks enter (script code from: https://automationtestingsimplified.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/how-to-handle-window-based-pop-up-using-selenium-and-autoit/).

Problem to solve: 
Selenium throws "UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present", although the modal dialog is already accepted.

I tried:

- Accessing Modal dialog via alert-api. Problem here is, I can not fill
  in username. Even if I use Robot.
  "driver.switchTo().alert().accept();" also doesn't work.
- Let the driver wait till alert isn't present with
  "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()));"
- To accept the dialog, event if it already has been accepted.

Possible solution: 
Ignore dialog or set it as not present in the driver. But I can't find a solution for that.

Comment: is it possible to provide a link for that webpage

Comment: Since it is a internal page for company use only, I cannot provide any links. But it is running on a JBoss EAP 6.2 and uses old fashioned JSF 1.2 together with seam and some other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Im Running into the same problem. until I find a better solution i'm using Robot to send the keys to the alert to accept it

```
private void acceptAlert() {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```